# Manually close Bootstrap dropdown with multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have such a dropdown menu:

[image]

It works fine, but **I need to add a manual `Close` button to it** similar to this:

[image]

so that the Dropdown closes just like I would have clicked anywhere else on the page.

I looked at Bootstrap manuals and searched Google, but couldn't find a solution for this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try the following (put this in an `on-click`):

```
$('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');
```

Hence, your button would look like:

```
<button onclick="$('[data-toggle="dropdown"]').parent().removeClass('open');"> x </button>
```